# Authenticator with retrofit, dont just return null when a access token can not be added

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

the api I am working with returns a 401 for various reasons. Not just that my token has expired. Im not sure how to return that information in my call.

So for example I might get a 401 becuase the user has invalid grants.
im checking for this in my authenticator by

```
   @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {......


String reponsebody = response.body().string();
            if(reponsebody!=null){
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(reponsebody);
                    if(obj.getString("message").equals("Invalid Grants")){
                        return null;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Except I dont want to return just "null" which would fire onError in my Observer.. Id like to return something that I can use to decide the best course of action.

I've thought about trying to modify the response code to something else, but had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: If you control the server add an error code to your response. Then parse it and act accordingly. Here is an example showing what sort of error codes you might want to have ([link](https://developer.yahoo.com/brightroll/dsp/api/docs/reporting/errors/)). Also have a look at GsonConverterFactory. Out of my experience your code will get messy without it.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, that would be my final course of action... Request the backend be modified to use a different code. If its not possible, I was hoping to manage the issue myself. I've tried adding an interceptor before the authenticator to see if I could modify it before it hits the authenticator, but no such luck.